# MVC allow users to view xml instead of downloading

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a dump of xml files in `/Content/MyXML/` that I want users to be able to view when they click on a link to the xml file.

Currently if I click the link or access the URL directly, it pops up as a download in the browser, rather than just viewing it.

In the `/Content/MyXML/` folder I have placed this web.config (otherwise I just got 404 errors when trying to access the xml files)

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script, Read">
        <clear />
        <add path="*.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" name="xml allow" />
        <add path="*.xml.gz" verb="GET" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" name="xml gz allow" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there anything I can add to the web.config to make browsers view the xml instead of downloading it?

Comment: try http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-XML-File-in-Web-Browser-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but trying to find a web.config only solution for now

Comment: try http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/modifying-web.config-to-serve-site.xml-and-static-files-with-orchard-cms

Comment: Same thing as the web.config I already have. Just downloads the file instead of viewing in browser